# Unable to infer the XSD from the XML file. The XML contains multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

When i try to Generate my XSD File from my XML File in SSIS ,i get the following Error specified Below

**Unable to infer the XSD from the XML file. The XML contains multiple namespaces.**

Below is the code to my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfCountryCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Canada</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Canada</Description>
  </CountryCode>
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">GreatBritain</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Great Britain and Wales</Description>
  </CountryCode>
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">IrelandNorthern</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Northern Ireland</Description>
  </CountryCode>
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">IrelandRepublicOf</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Republic of Ireland</Description>
  </CountryCode>
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Scotland</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">Scotland</Description>
  </CountryCode>
  <CountryCode>
    <Code xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">UnitedStates</Code>
    <Description xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">United States</Description>
  </CountryCode>
</ArrayOfCountryCode>
```

Any idea how to fix this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different tool.

The oXygen XSD generator does quite a reasonable job on this one, producing two schema documents, one for each namespace.